# How to create template for single record and render it?

Tags: templates, meteor

Maybe it is a silly question but consider this scenario: I have on site records list and area where I want to show record details. How to implement this functionality using meteor template:

when I click on record in records list, area with record details is refreshed and it is displaying this clicked record details. I don't want routing, changing url, only this simple functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Session variable to store the clicked id and grab the data using a helper based on the session id.

Answer (score 0):

In click event you create Session like

```
Session.set("name",this);
```

but you have to keep in mind this event have to be inside `#each` loop. 
In template where you want to keep your data you wrap all this with handlebar `{{#with session}}` and your helper should look like

```
session: function(){ 
  return Session.get("name");
}
```

Inside of it you can use everything like in #each loop